# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.loginapp/com.android.loginapp.login}

Tags: android

This error is causing my application to stop every time I run it and cant figure out why. Think it may be an issue in the XML file but can't see it.

It says `Unfortunately login app has stopped working`

Here is the code:

**login.java**

```
public class login extends Activity {

public static final String MY_PREFS = "SharedPreferences";
private DatabaseAdapter dbHelper;
private EditText theUsername;
private EditText thePassword;
private Button loginButton;
private Button registerButton;
private Button clearButton;
private Button exitButton;
private CheckBox rememberDetails;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SharedPreferences mySharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS, 0);
    Editor editor = mySharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putLong("uid", 0);
    editor.commit();

    dbHelper = new DatabaseAdapter(this);
    dbHelper.open();

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    initControls();
}

private void initControls() {
    //Set the activity layout.
    theUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Username);
    thePassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Password);
    loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Login);
    registerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Register);
    //clearButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Clear);
    //exitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Exit);
    rememberDetails = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.RememberMe);

    //Create touch listeners for all buttons.
    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick (View v){
            LogMeIn(v);
        }
    });

    registerButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick (View v){
            Register(v);
        }
    });

    clearButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick (View v){
            ClearForm();
        }
    });

    exitButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick (View v){
            Exit();
        }
    });
    //Create remember password check box listener.
    rememberDetails.setOnClickListener(new CheckBox.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick (View v){
            RememberMe();
        }
    });

    //Handle remember password preferences.
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS, 0);
    String thisUsername = prefs.getString("username", "");
    String thisPassword = prefs.getString("password", "");
    boolean thisRemember = prefs.getBoolean("remember", false);
    if(thisRemember) {
        theUsername.setText(thisUsername);
        thePassword.setText(thisPassword);
        rememberDetails.setChecked(thisRemember);
    }

}

/**
 * Deals with Exit option - exits the application.
 */
private void Exit()
{
    finish();
}

/**
 * Clears the login form.
 */
private void ClearForm() {
    saveLoggedInUId(0,"","");
    theUsername.setText("");
    thePassword.setText("");
}

/**
 * Handles the remember password option.
 */
private void RememberMe() {
    boolean thisRemember = rememberDetails.isChecked();
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS, 0);
    Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("remember", thisRemember);
    editor.commit();
}

/**
 * This method handles the user login process.  
 * @param v
 */
private void LogMeIn(View v) {
    //Get the username and password
    String thisUsername = theUsername.getText().toString();
    String thisPassword = thePassword.getText().toString();

    //Assign the hash to the password
    thisPassword = md5(thisPassword);

    // Check the existing user name and password database
    Cursor theUser = dbHelper.fetchUser(thisUsername, thisPassword);
    if (theUser != null) {
        startManagingCursor(theUser);
        if (theUser.getCount() > 0) {
            saveLoggedInUId(theUser.getLong(theUser.getColumnIndex(DatabaseAdapter.COL_ID)), thisUsername, thePassword.getText().toString());
            stopManagingCursor(theUser);
            theUser.close();
            Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), Helloworld.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

        //Returns appropriate message if no match is made
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                    "You have entered an incorrect username or password.", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            saveLoggedInUId(0, "", "");
        }
        stopManagingCursor(theUser);
        theUser.close();
    }

    else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                "Database query error", 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

/**
 * Open the Registration activity.
 * @param v
 */
private void Register(View v)
{
    Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), Register.class);
    startActivity(i);
}

private void saveLoggedInUId(long id, String username, String password) {
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS, 0);
    Editor myEditor = settings.edit();
    myEditor.putLong("uid", id);
    myEditor.putString("username", username);
    myEditor.putString("password", password);
    boolean rememberThis = rememberDetails.isChecked();
    myEditor.putBoolean("rememberThis", rememberThis);
    myEditor.commit();
}

/**
 * Deals with the password encryption. 
 * @param s The password.
 * @return
 */
private String md5(String s) {
    try {
        MessageDigest digest = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        digest.update(s.getBytes());
        byte messageDigest[] = digest.digest();

        StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i=0; i<messageDigest.length; i++)
            hexString.append(Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]));

        return hexString.toString();
    } 

    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        return s;
    }
}
}
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="#E6E6E6" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:background="#46C1EF"
    android:gravity="center|fill_vertical"
    android:text="MemRar"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblLogin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="51dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="71dp"
    android:text="Login:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#223355" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/Username"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lblLogin"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lblLogin"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:hint="Username"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:lines="1"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/Password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Username"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Username"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Username"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:lines="1"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Login"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/RememberMe"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:background="#46C1EF"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/Login" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Register"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Login"
    android:background="#46C1EF"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/Register" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/RememberMe"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Password"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Password"
    android:textColor="#223355"
    android:text="Remember Me" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: show.the.stacktrace.or.even.better.read.it.first.and.fix.the.crash.pointed.out.there.

Comment: i see only code but no stacktrace which will indicate the casue of the crash

Comment: Lol why do you have `public void Exit() { finish(); }`... just call `finish();` - that method is clutter.

Comment: `//clearButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Clear);
    //exitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Exit);` is commented giving you NullPointerException

Answer (score 2):

You have commented out the code that initializes the references to clear and exit buttons but still invoke `setOnClickListener()` on these `null` button references.

Answer (score 2):

You have

```
//clearButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Clear);
//exitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Exit);
```

Comemnted which should give you `NUllPointerException`. There might be more mistakes in which case you should post a stacktrace.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you, new to Android and still learning the ropes